# Room (SQLite) WHERE clause with null arguments doesn't work

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have entity class `Person` and I want to query persons from database by `feature` which may or may not be null. When I set feature to non-null the query works but when the feature is null the query returns empty list. What I am doing wrong?

**TEST**

```java
Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
AppDb db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, AppDb.class).allowMainThreadQueries().build();
PersonDao dao = db.personDao();

dao.insert(new Person("El Risitas", "Funny"));
dao.insert(new Person("Elon Musk", "Alien"));
dao.insert(new Person("Donald Trump", null));

assertEquals(3, dao.getAll().size());

assertEquals("Funny", dao.getByFeature("Funny").get(0).getFeature());

// fails because dao.getByFeature(null) = EMPTY LIST
assertEquals(null, dao.getByFeature(null).get(0).getFeature());
```

**Person.java**

```java
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity(tableName = "person")
public class Person {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "id") @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) private int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") private String name;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "feature") private String feature;

    public Person(String name, String feature) {
        this.name = name;
        this.feature = feature;
    }
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
    public int getId() { return id; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getFeature() { return feature; }
}
```

**PersonDao.java**

```java
import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.Query;
import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface PersonDao {

    @Insert
    void insert(Person person);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM person")
    List<Person> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM person WHERE feature = :feature")
    List<Person> getByFeature(String feature);

}
```

**AppDb.java**

```java
import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;

@Database(
        version = 1,
        exportSchema = false,
        entities = {Person.class}
)
public abstract class AppDb extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract PersonDao personDao();
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In SQL, nothing is ever equal to null. (Nothing is ever *not* equal to null, either.) You have to use `is null`. So your query could be something like (untested)

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE feature = :feature or (feature is null and :feature is null)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `IS` operator instead of `=`.

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE feature IS :feature
```

From [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> The IS and IS NOT operators work like = and != except when one or both
> of the operands are NULL. In this case, if both operands are NULL,
> then the IS operator evaluates to 1 (true) and the IS NOT operator
> evaluates to 0 (false). If one operand is NULL and the other is not,
> then the IS operator evaluates to 0 (false) and the IS NOT operator is
> 1 (true). It is not possible for an IS or IS NOT expression to
> evaluate to NULL.