# Room Database - How to filter with nullable list - where null indicates "accept all"?

Tags: java, kotlin, android-room

I'm constructing a room database query with optional filters.  You can either pass in a set of values to accept, or `null` - meaning "accept everything".

Signature:

```kotlin
@Dao
interface DetectionDao {
    ...

    @Query("SELECT * FROM DETECTION " +
            "WHERE :sessionIds IS NULL OR sessionId IN (:sessionIds) " +
            "AND :sources IS NULL OR source in (:sources) " +
            "AND :labels IS NULL OR label in (:labels)"
    )
    fun getFilteredDetections(sessionIds: List<String>?, sources: List<String>?, labels: List<String>?): List<Detection>
}
```

The problem is that when I try to invoke this method with nulls, I get an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
    at com.dji.videostreamdecodingsample.DetectionDao_Impl.getFilteredDetections(DetectionDao_Impl.java:500)
```

Basically indicating that Room doesn't understand that the argument is nullable.

Is there some easy work around for this?

Comment: Seems like duplicate of [Room (SQLite) WHERE clause with null arguments doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56956369/room-sqlite-where-clause-with-null-arguments-doesnt-work).

Comment: Looking at it - it seems different to me - there they're trying to match a null value in the database.  Here there are no nulls in the database - I'm just trying to use null in the query to indicate a wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround.  Just use a wrapper method in the Database access object.  Would still be nice for Room to support this internally so no wrapper is necessary.  But this works for now.

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM DETECTION " +
            "WHERE :acceptAllSessions OR sessionId IN (:sessionIds) " +
            "AND :acceptAllSources OR source in (:sources) " +
            "AND :acceptAllLabels OR label in (:labels)"
    )
    fun getFilteredDetections(
        sessionIds: List<String>, acceptAllSessions: Boolean,
        sources: List<String>, acceptAllSources: Boolean,
        labels: List<String>, acceptAllLabels: Boolean
    ): List<Detection>

    /** Wrapper to allow you to indicate wildcard by providing null for the filter-list */
    fun getFilteredDetections(sessionIds: List<String>?, sources: List<String>?, labels: List<String>?): List<Detection> =
        getFilteredDetections(
            sessionIds = sessionIds?: emptyList(), acceptAllSessions = sessionIds==null,
            sources = sources?: emptyList(), acceptAllSources = sources==null,
            labels = labels?: emptyList(), acceptAllLabels = labels==null,
        )
```